# Why Strong Params contains permitted: false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I put in a `binding.pry` at the top of my controller's `update` action.  Once at that break point, I put in `params[:foo_bar]` to examine the `params` hash.  Here is what I get:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"123==", "foobar"=><ActionController::Parameters {"barbazz_attributes"=>{"start_date"=>"08/27/2016", "end_date"=>"08/29/2016", "id"=>"89"}, "bazz_id"=>"3", "abc_id"=>"330", "bazzbazz_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"1", "city_id"=>"1669", "id"=>"26"}, "1"=>{"city_id"=>"1681", "id"=>"27"}, "2"=>{"city_id"=>"1672"}}} permitted: false>, "cat_id"=>["1", "1", "1"], "commit"=>"Update FooBar", "controller"=>"foo_bars", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"52"} permitted: false>
```

I assumed `permitted: false` is there because I did not whitelist some attributes.  I looked over the attributes and it appears to me that I did whitelist everything.

I am using Rails 5 if that happens to make any difference.

**Question**: What is an easy way to find out why the strong parameters are returning `params: false`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't access params directly with `params` instead use the name you gave your permitted params, for example: `foobar_params`.

If `foobar_params` is defined:

```
def foobar_params
  params.require(:foobar).permit ...
end
```

The easiest way is to read the source code for [ActionController::Parameter](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/blob/master/lib/action_controller/parameters.rb#L42), `permitted = false` is the default unless you call `permit!` to allow all, but that defeats the purpose of strong parameters.

Comment: Thanks!  When I use `foobar_params` it now shows `permitted: true`.  I knew it was going to be something simple!

Comment: It always is! This is to prevent you from inadvertently using params on `Foobar.create` for example.